# How do you determine the network transfer speed of a Windows application?

Tags: c#, windows, networking

I would like to determine the network usage of my application. It uses various methods for data transfer (web services, net.tcp WCF contracts, P2P contracts) so I guess I'm interested in the statistics for the running process. Something like uTorrent displays for it's total transfer rates.

Comment: is this to integrate into the program itself so it can be displayed to the end user, or simply for you to profile/monitor?

Comment: For the end user, to notify them that there's activity (for a p2p data app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to use IpHelperApi, I'll post some more info on how it goes.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/iphlpapi.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is a very powerful network analysis tool.  Is does more than you are asking for as it allows packet inspection of everything passing your network card.

However, it does have some nice analysis tools so you can capture the network traffic from your application and look at its IO profile over time, filter by IP address or protocol, save snapshots, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Netlimiter 2 Monitor](http://www.netlimiter.com/download.php).

Answer (score 0):

How many different servers and protocols are in the picture?  You managed to list quite a smorgashbord.  You are trying to gauge overall usage, or by server, or by protocol

Comment: Overall usage. I was hoping there would be a way to get the info from Windows to tell me the in/out transfer rates for that pid.

Answer (score 0):

Performance monitors will provide you with the information you require at process level.